# What is the geometrical interpretation of this vector identity (Binet-Cauchy identity)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis

Sometimes I use this identity really useful to solve the problem,
$$\mathbf{\left(A\times B\right)\cdot}\left(\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{D}\right)=\left(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{C}\right)\left(\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{D}\right)-\left(\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{C}\right)\left(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{D}\right)$$
I know this is derived from Binet-Cauchy identity,
$$\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i c_i\biggr)
\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j d_j\biggr) = 
\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i d_i\biggr)
\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j c_j\biggr) 
+ \sum_{1\le i < j \le n} 
(a_i b_j - a_j b_i ) 
(c_i d_j - c_j d_i )$$
But what is the geometrical meaning of this identity? Can anyone explain this without using too many equations?

Comment: It might be good to start with a geometrical interpretation of the formula for $\mathbf{A}\cdot(\mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{C})$, which is the volume of a parallelipiped.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Binet_formula#Geometric_interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Binet_formula#Geometric_interpretations)

Comment: Note this is essentially the [Lagrange identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Answer (score 1):

In brief, you can interpret $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}$ as the vectorial area of the parallelogram spanned by $\mathbf{a, b}$. It's really just a vector orthogonal to both with magnitude equal to that area. Then the Binet-Cauchy identity is just the inner product of two such vectors.

---

In more detail: it follows from the natural way to define an inner product on [pseudovectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector), which is what the cross product 'gives'. By natural I mean, if you just treat your pseudovectors like vectors, this is the same dot product operation as vectors also.

It is easier to see what's going on if you write it like this:

$\mathbf{(a \times b) \cdot (c \times d) = (a \otimes b) \cdot (c \otimes d - d \otimes c)}$

Make both sides symmetric with a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$:

$\mathbf{(a \times b) \cdot (c \times d) = \frac{1}{2}(a \otimes b - b \otimes a) \cdot (c \otimes d - d \otimes c)}$

Where the dot product on tensor products is defined elementwise. Note that the components of $\mathbf{a \otimes b - b \otimes a} \in \otimes^2 \mathbb{R}^3$ are $a_i b_j  - b_i a_j$, which are exactly the components of the cross product.

The similarity is because the cross product *is* the wedge product $\mathbf{a \wedge b = a \otimes b - b \otimes a} \in \wedge^2 \mathbb{R}^3$, followed by the [Hodge Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) operator which maps antisymmetric elements of $\wedge^2 \mathbb{R}^3$ to elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$, via $\star \mathbf{(x \wedge y)} = \mathbf{z}$, etc. So this identity says:

$\mathbf{(a \times b) \cdot (c \times d)} =\mathbf{\star (a \wedge b) \cdot \star (c \wedge d)} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{(a \wedge b) \cdot (c \wedge d)}  $

In order to let the inner product on $\wedge^2 \mathbb{R}^3$ be preserved by $\star$,  we have to [define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Inner_product) a new inner product on $\wedge^2$ as the inner product from $\otimes^2$, but divided by $2$ (or by $k!$ in the general case). Then everything works out.

At least, I assume that's why we do it that way. I suppose you could also define that $\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\mathbf{a \otimes b - b \otimes a})$, if you wanted to keep using the tensor algebra's induced inner product, but that's klunky in other ways.

---